# Java jsoup link selecting

Tags: java, html, css, jsoup

I have the following code:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(mainPage).get();

Elements section = doc.select("#main");
Elements allArtTags = section.select("article");
for (Element artTag : allArtTags ){
    Elements atags = artTag.select("a");
}
```

As you see first I am selecting the `#main` and then `"article"` , finally for each element getting the link with `select("a")`, my question is can this code be optimized in some way so to display again the same links but in more optimized way(or less code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can this code be optimized in some way so to display again the same links but in more optimized way(or less code)

Write the code like below:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(mainPage).get();
for (Element aTag : doc.select("#main article a")){

}
```